# Proactive caching can only be deployed to a server running Enterpise or Developer

Tags: ssrs-2008, sql-server

When deploying cubes and setting Automatic MOLAP to show changes I noticed the message:

**Proactive caching can only be deployed to a server running Microsoft SQL Server Enterpise Edition or Developer Edition.**  (I noticed changes are not showing up in my reports.  Is this why?)

I'm unlcear about wording of the error.  My Analysis Server is Developer, but the SQL server on which the data is stored in Standard.  Does the source database need to be Developer/Enterprise, or is it good enough that my Analysis Server is?

Am I out of luck when it comes to reports that show data that changes throughout the day?  Or is there a way around this without upgrading the source server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Proactive caching can only be deployed to a server running Microsoft
>   **SQL Server** Enterpise Edition or Developer Edition."

You've answered your own question there.

Comment: I'm still getting accustomed to the fact that 'SQL' Server Management Studio opens non-SQL server types.  Thx